# PROBLEM: user's entry isn't being saved properly

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

The general purpose of this section of code is to allow the user to fill in the form, and then use the CURRENT GUEST button to print the entries. However, it outputs:

`[('', '', 'Male', '', '', '2020-07-31', '2020-07-31', 0, 0, 1),`
(the user's inputs should be where the '' are).

This is a link to the code (too big to add)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vd6NvMgCzvx5iRTb54EE_eMYZAS9MAj5tZ8VNSv5w5Y/edit?usp=sharing

I've been watching tutorials and trying to lean but with no avail; please help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] created specifically for this question. Links to code on other sites isn't appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: It is because you have used multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `addGuest()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks you; it worked. Is there any way to upvote or increase your reputation for all your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used multiple instances of `Tk()`. Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `addGuest()` function.